# XPath : Return a default value for missing tag in list

Tags: xpath

I have a simple list I want to query :

```
<ul>
<li>List1 <a href="ref1">something</a></li>
<li>List2 <a href="ref2">something</a></li>
<li>List3</li>
<li>List4 <a href="ref4">something</a></li>
</ul>
```

What I want to return is a list of all the href values. Note that for list element 3 (List3) I want to return a string 'noRef'.

So the result would be : ref1,ref2,noRef,ref3

if I do something like `//ul/li/a/@href` I will get a list : ref1,ref2,ref3 (note the missing string)

Is there an Xpath I can use to substitute the string if there is an absence of the  element?

Comment: Thanks. I will do that. I suppose there is a way to get the entire <ul> blob?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that's what I ended up doing.. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
ul/li/(a/@href/string(), 'noHref')[1]
```

Comment: Thanks Max. I tried that and it doesn't seem to compile. I tried it in a few places and my test at [link](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath) gave me the following error : "Failed to evaluate XPath expression: A location step was expected following the '/' or '//' token."

Comment: @VincentFumo Cannot be done in pure XPath v1.0. You have to `foreach li` then `if a then a/@href else 'noRef'` in whatever language you are using.